# Need help on indexing using SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, indexing

I have a table, `paymentdetails`, with a column `paymentstatus` (has a check constraint restricting values to either paid or pending). Also, a table `patientdetails`, that holds patientid, address......columns

I want to create an index that speeds up the execution of extracting the patient details for each patient whose initial payment is pending.

Comment: Indexing the foreign key column is the first thing I'd suggest.  But understand that an index doesn't ensure a performance increase, and negatively impacts insertion/updating.

Answer (score 2):

Write your query first. Look at at what the query cares about.

You'll want an index on any keys that are involved in joins, on those in the where clause, and perhaps on the primary key of the table that most heavily informs the result set (perhaps using `INCLUDE` to have other columns in the result set available without hitting the table).

A "filtered index" (SQLServer terminology for partial indices, for some unknown reason) would be good, but SQLServer has only had these since 2008.

But the former is theory and the latter is just a nice-to-know until such a time as you start using 2008. Practical examination of how the query is executed is the real thing.

Also think about the fact that your indices will speed up other SELECTs, and the WHERE part of UPDATEs and DELETEs, but will otherwise slightly slow down UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT. Hence you don't want to go nuts putting indices absolutely everywhere, but you do want to be particularly keen on those most likely to be used in other queries.